# Fix broken eBook Table of Contents?

Tags: epub, calibre, table-of-contents, container.xml

The Table of Contents of [this .ePub file](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1250) seems to incorrectly link to one page previous to the desired page. For instance if 'Part 2' is clicked, it directs to the last page of 'Part 1'. I have looked over the source files, but it is unclear to me how I can rectify this issue.

Any help in fixing this file will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the chapter file names were incorrectly listed in the OEBPS TOC.

I resolved the issue by:

1. Opening the first file (navigational TOC) in the OEBPS folder of the unpacked .ePub (.zip)
2. Correcting the 'h-#' portion of the href  in each  tag by incrementing by 1. For instance, the first href which was `"@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@1250@1250-h@1250-h-0.htm.html#link2H_PART1"`, becomes `"@public@vhost@g@gutenberg@html@files@1250@1250-h@1250-h-1.htm.html#link2H_PART1"`.
3. Saving and repackaging the .ePub

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the anchor tags were put in the wrong place. If you unzip the .epub, you'll see that the link for Part 1

```
<p><a id="link2H_PART1"><!--  H2 anchor --></a></p>
```

is at the end of the first (navigational TOC) file, `1250-h-0.htm.html` rather than the file for Part 1, `1250-h-1.htm.html`.

If you move each of those links to the beginning of the correct file (right after the `<body>` tag and before the `<h2>` would be a good place) then that should fix your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but it seems as if the solution was something else